# Change Text Color of Disabled Java Button with HTML text

Tags: java, swing

I have a java swing button with multi-line text, I used `<HTML>` tag as follows:

```
button.setText("<html><center><font color = white>Reset<br>Diagram</font></html>");
```

But when I set `button.setEnabled(false);`, the text color becomes light blue, while the rest of button without `<HTML>` tag have the text color gray when disabled.

I tried using UIManager, but it only worked for buttons without `<HTML>` tag:

```
UIManager.put("Button.disabledText", new ColorUIResource(Color.GRAY));
```

Any idea on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled Swing components with [html formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) use a uniform foreground color taken from the UIManager by key "textInactiveText". The key was introduced as fix for [JDK-4783068](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4783068) - further refinement to allow per-component disabled color rejected in [JDK-7150926](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7150926).

Obviously the value depends on the LaF - the light blue (only?) configured by Metal (actually, the Ocean Theme). Applications can replace the default setting, f.i. with standard button's disabled text color

```
UIManager.put("textInactiveText", UIManager.get("Button.disabledText"));
```

or a hard-coded color

```
UIManager.put("textInactiveText", new ColorUIResource(Color.GRAY));
```

For Metal, we could also implement and use a custom theme which returns the color from its `getInactiveSystemTextColor()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `JLayer` to replace the disabled `JButton` drawing?

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public final class ButtonDisabledTextTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    UIManager.put("Button.disabledText", Color.GRAY);
    String html = "<html><center><font color = white>Reset<br>Diagram</font>";
    JButton button0 = makeButton(html);
    JButton button1 = makeButton(html);

    JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("setEnabled", true);
    check.addActionListener(e -> {
      boolean isSelected = ((JCheckBox) e.getSource()).isSelected();
      button0.setEnabled(isSelected);
      button1.setEnabled(isSelected);
    });

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(button0);
    p.add(new JLayer<>(button1, new DisabledHtmlTextLayerUI<>()));
    p.add(check);
    return p;
  }

  private static JButton makeButton(String title) {
    JButton b = new JButton(title);
    b.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    return b;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ButtonDisabledTextTest().makeUI());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class DisabledHtmlTextLayerUI<V extends AbstractButton> extends LayerUI<V> {
  private final JButton button = new JButton();
  private final JPanel canvas = new JPanel();

  @Override public void updateUI(JLayer<? extends V> l) {
    super.updateUI(l);
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(button);
  }

  @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    if (c instanceof JLayer) {
      Component view = ((JLayer<?>) c).getView();
      super.paint(g, (JComponent) view);
      if (!view.isEnabled()) {
        paintDisabledText(g, view);
      }
    }
  }

  private void paintDisabledText(Graphics g, Component c) {
    if (c instanceof AbstractButton) {
      AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton) c;
      button.setFont(b.getFont());
      button.setText("<html><center><font color = gray>Reset<br>Diagram</font>");
      button.setIcon(b.getIcon());
      button.setVerticalAlignment(b.getVerticalAlignment());
      button.setHorizontalAlignment(b.getHorizontalAlignment());
      button.setVerticalTextPosition(b.getVerticalTextPosition());
      button.setHorizontalTextPosition(b.getHorizontalTextPosition());
      // button.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.disabledText"));
      // button.setOpaque(false);
      button.setOpaque(true);
      button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      Rectangle r = b.getBounds();
      SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g2, button, canvas, r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
      g2.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer, but @kleopatra provided an easier solution that just worked.